# Python: How to upload folder to Google Drive

Tags: python, python-3.x

i want to upload a local folder to google drive with python

Folder example

```
1 folder level
C:\Users\test\Documents\google drvie\test\

the folder you want to upload
Folder name: upload
C:\Users\test\Documents\google drvie\test\upload

* In the upload folder
There is still a hierarchy of folders and files.
I want to upload all folders and files in upload.

C:\Users\test\Documents\google drvie\test\upload\upload2
C:\Users\test\Documents\google drvie\test\upload\test.txt
C:\Users\test\Documents\google drvie\test\upload\upload2\uplpad3
C:\Users\test\Documents\google drvie\test\upload\upload2\uplpad3\test.txt
```

I did it with the script below, but I can't upload by folder.
Only files can be uploaded.

When uploading by folder, the following access permission error is displayed.
If anyone knows, I would appreciate it if you could tell me.

error contents
**Traceback**

```
GoogleDriveFile({'parents': [{'id': '1J8TXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'}], 'title': 'upload'})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\test\Documents\google drvie\googledrive_file_up.py", line 43, in <module>
    f.SetContentFile(os.path.join(path,x))
  File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pydrive\files.py", line 169, in SetContentFile
    self.content = open(filename, 'rb')
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\test\\Documents\\google drvie\\test\\upload'
```

Reference page
[How to Upload File to Google Drive using Python Script?](https://www.projectpro.io/recipes/upload-files-to-google-drive-using-python)

code

```
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth

import os

#Authenticate Google services
gauth = GoogleAuth()

# load credentials or create empty credentials if none exist
gauth.LoadCredentialsFile("mycreds.txt")

#If you don't have Google service credentials
if gauth.credentials is None:
     #Automatically receive authorization code from user and configure local web server
     gauth. LocalWebserverAuth()
# if the access token does not exist or has expired
elif gauth.access_token_expired:
     #refresh authorization for google services
     gauth. Refresh()
# if none match
else:
     #Authorize Google services
     gauth. Authorize()
# save credentials to file in txt format
gauth.SaveCredentialsFile("mycreds.txt")
       
#Authentication process for Google Drive
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

# specify folder path to upload
path = r'C:\Users\test\Documents\google drvie\test'
# File ID to upload to GOOGLE DRIVE
folder_id='1J8TXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
Loop processing (repeated processing) by #for statement
for x in os.listdir(path):
     # Create GoogleDriveFile object
     #f = drive.CreateFile({'title' : x})
     f = drive.CreateFile({"parents": [{"id": folder_id},]})
     #file title
     f['title'] = x
     # set local file and upload
     print(f)
     f.SetContentFile(os.path.join(path,x))
     print(f)
     #Upload to Google Drive
     f.Upload()
     print(f)

     f = None
```

Sorry for the inconvenience, but thank you in advance.

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is.  Please edit the question and add the whole error traceback message.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this thing somehow?